# Slither: when I run `slither . --print call-graph` I get: AttributeError: 'FunctionTopLevel' object has no attribute 'contract_declarer'

Tags: hardhat, slither

Compiled with hardhat.

I faced an issue(log):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 826, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 97, in process_all
    ) = process_single(compilation, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 77, in process_single
    return _process(slither, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 133, in _process
    printer_results = slither.run_printers()
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/slither.py", line 218, in run_printers
    return [p.output(self._crytic_compile.target).data for p in self._printers]
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/slither.py", line 218, in <listcomp>
    return [p.output(self._crytic_compile.target).data for p in self._printers]
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/printers/call/call_graph.py", line 244, in output
    ["strict digraph {"] + [_process_functions(all_functions_as_dict.values())] + ["}"]
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/printers/call/call_graph.py", line 180, in _process_functions
    all_contracts.add(function.contract_declarer)
AttributeError: 'FunctionTopLevel' object has no attribute 'contract_declarer'
Error in .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 826, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 97, in process_all
    ) = process_single(compilation, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 77, in process_single
    return _process(slither, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 133, in _process
    printer_results = slither.run_printers()
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/slither.py", line 218, in run_printers
    return [p.output(self._crytic_compile.target).data for p in self._printers]
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/slither.py", line 218, in <listcomp>
    return [p.output(self._crytic_compile.target).data for p in self._printers]
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/printers/call/call_graph.py", line 244, in output
    ["strict digraph {"] + [_process_functions(all_functions_as_dict.values())] + ["}"]
  File "/home/internos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slither/printers/call/call_graph.py", line 180, in _process_functions
    all_contracts.add(function.contract_declarer)
AttributeError: 'FunctionTopLevel' object has no attribute 'contract_declarer'
```

When I try execute following command: slither . --print call-graph

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?
Or where I need to dig to solve this problem?